# infopath 2010 person and group retrive email

Tags: infopath

i want to make the code send email that is picked from active directory inside a text box

```
 XPathNavigator dataSource;
 dataSource = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
 string toAddress = dataSource.SelectSingleNode
("/my:myFields/my:toAddress/pc:Person/pc:AccountId",NamespaceManager).Value;
dataSource.SelectSingleNode("//my:field1",NamespaceManager).SetValue(this.User.UserName);
```

so how can i retrieve **person and group email** and put it **inside a text box** and which one of this i should use (account id or account type, display name ).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly disadvice to code in Infopath which is mostly the method of invoking more troubles than solving problems

The answer is provided in the detailed step-by-step instructions with screenshots by:

- Itay Shakury's [InfoPath - Get the current user without writing code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx)
- Clayton Cobb's [InfoPath – Get user information without writing code (extended)](http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/)
- Alana Helbig's [Use the Contact Selector in InfoPath to get user details – no code required](http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/Alana/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20)
- etc.

Let me know if they answered your question.